# Can we use angular project and that will use in my two different API backend projects (i.e. node and .net core)?

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core

For an example, I have one angular ui project that fetches values and perform operations.

I have one backend API project in .Net Core and now I want to reuse angular ui project with node js.

Is it possible? 
How to configure it and which are the main points to take care that angular project support both.

How can I deploy it?

Comment: It doesn't matter what technology you use, as long as the API's are exposed over standard protocols like HTTP, it can be consumed using Angular. This question is too broad and there is no single correct answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a client side application that run's in clients browser, as long as the REST API or service you connect has Same API endpoints and same object models  and authentication etc everything will work as intended.

REST is platform independent like the web services and also language independent. It doesn't matter if you use  `.Net Core` or some  nodejs framework.

Once the angular application is build ( `ng build --prod`) you get a bundled application files in dist folder you can host these files in any web sever just like you host normal `html` file.

The only change you have to make in the  the Angular application will be to change the host URL (if there is any change) normally configured in `environments` folder

Answer (score 0):

Take help of environment file and change the api as per your requirement.